# Are ServiceStack's validators instantiated with every new request or is it a Singleton?

Tags: servicestack

Are **ServiceStack's** validators instantiated with every new request or are they instantiated once and reused accross multiple requests (Singleton)?

Comment: FYI: in this thread, Jeremy Skinner of FluentValidation recommends Singleton scope for the Validator classes, due to expensive compilation of expression trees: https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/226880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validator is resolved and executed from the IOC like any other dependency. The default scope when registering an `IValidator` is `ReuseScope.None` which results in a new instance being resolved each time.